# Randomly Make A equation a Solve it Python

Tags: python

The idea of this code is to randomly make an addition equation and solve it. The code that I have so far is this

```
import random 
import string 
def random_problem(num_operations):
  eq = str(random.randint(1, 100))
  for _ in range(num_operations):
    eq += random.choice(["+"])
    eq += str(random.randint(1, 100))
  return eq
problem=print(random_problem(1)) 
equation = (problem)
equation = equation.translate({string.whitespace: None})
print(sum(int(i) for i in equation.split("+")))
```

The code worked until I added the solving algo. If you have an answer that would help a lot -Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need it to add a random set of numbers you could just use eval()

```
import random 

def random_problem(num_operations):

  eq = str(random.randint(1, 100))

  for _ in range(num_operations):
    eq += random.choice(["+"])
    eq += str(random.randint(1, 100))

  return eq

problem = random_problem(1)
print(problem)

solution = eval(problem)

print(solution)
```

This will work if you add more operators such as "*", "-", etc to your list.